# How to cache video in flutter better_player?

Tags: flutter, dart, video-streaming, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I'm using better_player to play a video in a flutter app.

The problem is when I rewind the video by 10 or 5 seconds, the video player re-downloads the streamed video from the seeked duration all over, which consumes bandwidth.

How do I make better_player plays the video from the cached stream when I rewind, instead of re-downloading the stream all over again?
Is there another plugin that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

They said better_player plugin have cache support, but i don't try it because there is no update more a year for that plugin. Now, i just use video_player and flutter_cache_manager. Not good for implementation because it will request video twice, one for stream in video_player and one for download to the cache manager.

Build app like tiktok or instagram reels need cache at the same time when stream the video, but still in issue until now https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28094